# Can a simple Riemannian metric on the disc be extended to a Zoll metric on the sphere?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, geometry

*Given a simple Riemannian metric $(D,g)$ on the two-disc---its geodesics have no conjugate point and the boundary of the disc is strictly convex---, is it possible to embed $(D,g)$ isometrically into a Zoll two-sphere?*

I'm also interested in the same question on the $n$-disc. A related question is whether one can distinguish a Zoll metric locally (or at least say: this metric cannot be Zoll because in the neighborhood of this point it does not behave in such and such way). I'm guessing the answer to this last question is **no** and this prompted the first question.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I think it is likely that the answer to your second question is 'no'. Remember that Guillemin proved that any odd function on the $2$-sphere is the first derivative of a conformal deformation of the round $2$-sphere through Zoll metrics.  I believe that his proof can be used to show that, for any given smooth metric $g$ on the $2$-disk, a small enough neighborhood of the origin is isometric to a disk on a Zoll $2$-sphere.  This would rule out any local obstruction.  I haven't gone through the details to check this, but it seems reasonable and probably could be done.

Comment: Oh, and I believe that your question does have an affirmative answer in the case of a rotationally symmetric simple metric.  I think that, in fact, Zoll's original construction of the rotationally symmetric metrics on the $2$-sphere with all geodesics closed shows this.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I was thinking the same thing but I was wondering if in higher dimensions there would be some local obstructions since the infinitesimal obstructions to be a deformation are also trickier (Kiyohara condition and so forth). 

Comment: @RobertBryant I am not sure about "rotational case": at least, what I was thinking about Zoll's original construction (written up by Berger in his lectures for example) is exactly the contrary: Zoll's surface of rotation has an equator and if you give me any function above the equator, I can continue it with another function below the equator to close this little "rotated cap" to some Zoll surface of rotation. Or I do not understand something?....

Comment: @alvarezpaiva Did you learn something new about the answer to this question since then?... I am very interested!