# Metric, admitting an open set of closed geodesics.

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Note: I changed the original question to the one, proposed by Robert Bryant in the comment below as it is better formulated.

Assume there is a metric on a manifold with a closed geodesic such that all nearby geodesics are closed too. What can be said about a metric near this geodesic? We do not require that all the geodesics are closed, so the question is local.
A good example is a sphere with a deformed metric near the poles, so all the geodesics near the equator are closed.

Comment: would yo be more precise: you mean an open set, in what topological space of curves?

Comment: @Pietro:  I think that the OP means to ask what you can say about a metric such that it has a closed geodesic for which all of the geodesics near that one are closed.  For example, if you were to modify the round metric on the sphere near the poles only, then the geodesics near the equator would continue to all be closed.  The OP is asking what one can say about metrics that are 'Zoll near a given geodesic'.

Comment: Robert, precisely. Thank you for reformulating the question as I was thinking how to make it better formulated.

Comment: Even if your metric is Zoll and all geodesics are closed it is very hard to say something about the metric that is not "dynamic" (e.g. behavior of jacobi fields and things like that). Do you have a more precise idea of what you want? 

Comment: @alvarezpaiva,

Roughly speaking I am interested in if there are any local restrictions on such a metric? Here by "local" I mean "close to a particular point on the geodesic", not to be confused with " close to the whole geodesic".

In particular: Can such a metric be flat near some point on the closed geodesic? This seems to be intuitively very unlikely and I am very curious about the strong argument.

Comment: @Axel: there is little that is intuitive about Zoll surfaces. If you allow Finsler metrics you can do really strange things. For example, you can make the polar circles flat (and Riemannian) and still have a Finsler metric on $S^2$ all of whose geodesics are great circles. Even in the Riemannian case it is not clear that you cannot construct a Zoll metric on the two sphere for which the north and south poles (in fact, the whole polar circles) are flat. If I had to bet, I would bet it can be done. There are very many Zoll metrics!

Comment: @alvarezpaiva. Thank you for such an interesting discussion. Are there examples of metrics in a small neighborhood of a point which can't be extended to Zoll?  In the other words is it true that "not many" germs of Riemannian metrics are Zoll globally?
If yes, then PROBABLY flat metrics can not be extended to Zoll ( that is basically the definition of the word 'probably' :)  )

Comment: @Axel: no, there are no examples of germs of Riemannian metrics that cannot possible form part of a Zoll manifold. I had asked that here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119332/ and you can see Robert Bryant's comments on that question. 

Comment: @alvarezpaiva. That is very fruitful. Do you actually have a reference to the Guillemin paper, mentioned there? My question is actually motivated be the following: to a large extend usual flat billiards on the plane are similar in dynamical behavior to geodesic flows with no boundaries. And the curvature of these " geodesic flows" is related to the properties of the billiard boundary curve. For example: 1) Billiard on the square "=" geodesic flow on the flat torus.
2)Hyperbolic billiards( e.g. Sinai billiard) ( piece-wise concave curve)"=" geodesic flow in negative curvature.
to be continued..

Comment: However in case of flat billiards you conjecturally can not have "Zoll closed orbits", whatever piecewise smooth boundary you have, so the analogy " billiards=geodesic flows" fails somewhere and I am quite interested where.

Comment: @Axel: surprisingly, *there are Zoll billiards!* They are Finsler, and you have to (very) slightly interpret "Zoll", but this turns out to be quite interesting in the geometry of numbers and convex geometry. The reference is being written (although it seems to be taking me forever). The Guillemin paper is T*he radon transform on zoll surfaces*  Advances in Mathematics, vol. 22, no. 1, pp. 85-119, 1976.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva. Thank you for the reference. Regarding Zoll billiards, that sounds very interesting and I would be very curious to look at the paper. And again it makes more intriguing the question why there are no Zoll billiards ( conjecturally) for usual flat Riemannian billiards. It is not clear what makes flat case so specific.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva Maybe I didn't get something from your discussion, but where can I read about "Zoll billiards" ?