# Are there local invariants for smooth planes?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, projective-geometry

A *smooth plane* is a smooth double fibration 
$$
\mathbb{RP}^2 \overset{\pi_1}{\longleftarrow} PT\mathbb{RP}^2 \overset{\pi_2}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{RP}^2
$$
where the system of curves $\pi_1(\pi_2^{-1}(x))$, $x \in \mathbb{RP}^2$, satisfy the projective properties: (1) through every two points there passes a unique curve, and (2) every two curves intersect exactly on one point. I will also say that "a smooth projective plane" is simply $RP^2$ provided with such a system of curves a being part of such a double fibration.

Smooth planes are a very special class of path geometries

**Definition.** A path geometry on a manifold $M$ is a smooth foliation of $1$-dimensional leaves in $PTM$ which are transversal to the fibers of $\pi: PTM \rightarrow M$ and such that the lift to $PTM$ (i.e., by taking tangent lines) of the projection of a leaf on $M$ is the leaf itself.

The *paths* are the projections of the leaves of the foliation and all we have is a fancy way to say that a path geometry is a system of curves whose tangent lines make up the whole projectivized tangent bundle and such that two curves are tangent at some point if and only if they are identical.

By an old theorem of Whitehead, if $M$ is provided with a path geometry, then for every point $x \in M$ there exists an open neighborhood $U_x \ni x$ such that any two points of $U_x$ are joined by a unique path lying entirely on $M$. Such neighborhoods are called *convex*. Note that on a convex neighborhood two paths intersect at most once and every two points determine a unique path. It makes sense then to ask whether every convex neighborhood in a two-dimensional path geometry can be embedded in a smooth plane.

**Question.** Given a path geometry in an open neighborhood $V$ around
 the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, does there exist a smaller open convex neighborhood $U$ $(0 \in U \subset V)$, a smooth plane $P$, and a smooth embedding
$$
f : U \longrightarrow P
$$
which sends each path of the path geometry into a path of the smooth plane?

This is somewhat related to the question [Can a simple Riemannian metric on the disc be extended to a Zoll metric on the sphere?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119332/can-a-simple-riemannian-metric-on-the-disc-be-extended-to-a-zoll-metric-on-the-s)

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer is yes, but I will need to check, and I can't remember where this is worked out. I definitely thought about this problem, years ago. I think that it is also known that your definition of smooth plane agrees with the definition of smooth projective plane that you can find in papers of Linus Kramer and Stefan Immervoll and their collaborators.

Comment: @BenMcKay. Thanks. It was you who told me some years ago that this was equivalent to the "standard" definition, but we didn't discuss this local problem. I'm hoping the answer is yes, but I can't quite see how to prove it.